# Why would JsTestDriver create a second instance of browser?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automation, jasmine, js-test-driver

I open FireFox and go to the capture URL ( localhost:9876/capture by default ).

I then run my jasmine tests via jstestdriver.

The output that says:

```
setting runnermode QUIET
Firefox: Reset
Firefox: Reset
...
Total 3 tests (Passed: 3; Fails: 0; Errors: 0) (3.00 ms)
  Firefox 14.0.1 Linux: Run 3 tests (Passed: 3; Fails: 0; Errors 0) (3.00 ms)
```

Even before running the tests, if I click "close" on Firefox, jstestdriver registers as having closed one instance, yet I still see the browser open. It appears that there are two instances of Firefox running after opening the capture and/or the server.

Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: Helping Dan in office: While the jstestdriver server is running it still thinks there's a slave browser in there, even though `ps aux | grep firefox` shows no browser running at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing browsers with Selenium RC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455083/capturing-browsers-with-selenium-rc)